# Move a checkout field label to the left in Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles, checkout

I have a very little CSS issue that don't know how to resolve.

I have moved the input form into [checkout](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/) a little in right, but looks like label dont move with form. Now looks like this:

[image]

I tried to customize CSS with that rules:

```css
form.checkout #billing_last_name_field, form.checkout 
#shipping_last_name_field {
float: none !important;
margin-top: -24px;
margin-left: 40px; // i added this but nothing changed.
}
```

Any help here?

what to change to make all fields equal?

[Link to product here](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add this additional CSS rule targeting the `<label>` html tag:

```css
form.checkout #billing_last_name_field label, 
form.checkout #shipping_last_name_field label{
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

It should work.